# Symfony2 bundle not registering

Tags: symfony, registry, bundle

I created a new bundle with app/console. Trying to get a simple hello printed, so I can move on. I autoloaded the namespace, registered the bundle, created a page but Symfony detects an exception:

```
Bundle "PageBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() function of your AppKernel.php file?
```

But I have already done that.

The log shows:

```
[2011-06-08 23:41:56] request.CRITICAL: InvalidArgumentException: Bundle "PageBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() function of your AppKernel.php file? (uncaught exception) at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 634
```

I also cleared the cached dev folder. Can anyone help me figure out whats wrong. I have done this before, it's the first time I'm having this problem. Something to do with bootstrap.php.cache

Thanks! Appreciate all the help.

CODE:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
    );

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Webmuch\PageBundle\WebmuchPageBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebConfiguratorBundle\SymfonyWebConfiguratorBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}
```

The bundle also shows as an active bundle in the profiler.

Comment: I removed the cache and bootstrap files. Then rebuilt bootstrap file from console. Still the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: Show us your registerBundles() function.

Comment: I've added it to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using /app_dev.php? Your setup indicates that you only want the WebmuchPageBundle() loaded if you're in a dev or test environment... if you put the new class instantiation into the array up above, it'll load no matter what your environment.

Comment: I am in the development environment. I know about the array above, I am using /app_dev.php. I just don't get what's wrong. It's such a small thing I wanna do.

Comment: I don't know is it make sense for today, but it seems there was a bit wrong path to Bundle class:

This one:
`$bundles[] = new Webmuch\PageBundle\WebmuchPageBundle();`

Replace with this one:
`$bundles[] = new Webmuch\PageBundle\PageBundle();`

Suppose should work ;)

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't look like a problem with the bootstrap cache (line 634 points to the `Kernel::getBundles()` method, which is what's throwing the exception), but just in case, there's a script that will rebuild it: `bin\build_bootstrap.php`. The cache exists to reduce the number of `require()`s that Symfony would need to make to load the core Symfony classes, and as long as you're using one of the betas, it's unlikely that there's anything actually wrong in there.

It sounds like it might be a naming problem: your error complains about the lack of a PageBundle, but according to your kernel, the bundle ought to be called WebmuchPageBundle. Have you referenced it properly in your `routing_dev.yml`? An example routing config would be:

```
page:
    resource: "@WebmuchPageBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

Because you've only defined that bundle for the dev & test environments, you should use `routing_dev.yml` and not `routing.yml`.

Next, check that the bundle class is named correctly. You should have a file in the root of your bundle (e.g. `src/Webmuch/PageBundle/WebmuchPageBundle.php`) with the following content:

```
namespace Webmuch\PageBundle;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class WebmuchPageBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

Oh and obviously check that the web server's user can read your bundle directory. I *think* that throws a different error, but it's worth checking!

Answer (score 3):

I had this error before. Check your routings!
Probably somewhere you have lines like this:

```
webmuch_page_hello_world:
    pattern:   /hello
    defaults: { _controller: PageBundle:Default:hello }
```

There "PageBundle" is not right. You should use "WebmuchPageBundle". So use it like this: **WebmuchPageBundle**:Default:hello